# Vagrant: undo all changes made by setting static private ip

Tags: vagrant

Vagrant was running great for me and now `vagrant up` takes forever to boot up:

```
default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
```

After about 30 of these messages and a few minutes later it finally goes through.

The only thing I changed was I set a private static ip address: 
 `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"` in the Vagrant file.

I have since commented this line out of the vagrant file.  How can I undo all changes that were made when I changed this setting?  I have deleted the files in `/var/lib/dhcp/` but this didn't seem to help.

Comment: Ya but I have spent alot of time installing ruby, rails and a bunch of other things on the virtual machine that I don't want to lose.  Is there a way to save all the stuff I have on there?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply - have you tried vagrant reload?

Comment: Yes, I was still experiencing a long delay although it eventually goes through.  Since then I've switched over to cloud9.  I may just have to create a new vagrant in the future.  Thanks